# cUrl still doesn't emulate browser completely, all https url calls blocked with server timeout

Tags: php, curl, browser, timeout, emulation

So I took the entire header of my browser and put it in my code, I still get a timeout. Could the difference be some other place than the $header array?

The extra lines of code gave me this response when I tried: 'Notice: Undefined index: request_header'

Here's the updated sample:

```
$useragent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; W…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0';

$header[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Cookie: BUI=qkubv5up4ttnn38gyvkshqt8o5…11770704889&hd=1511770705073"';
$header[] = 'Host: www.bol.com';
$header[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$header[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; W…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0';
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bol.com" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'  );    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,  true   );  // new
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  //''
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$pagedata = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);  
var_dump($info['request_header']); // gives 'Notice: Undefined index: request_header'
```

.
.
----> original question

So I've been reading the cUrl answers for days now and cobbled together the code below that I thought would fully emulate a browser call. Sure enough, it works when I run it at home, but at work, where I'm probably behind some security walls, I get a connection timeout (no response from server at url at all) from all https calls. The weird thing is, the exact same urls given inside a browser window from the same workstation work flawlessly every time.

So my question is, with the code below, how could anything in my network still detect the call is originating from curl and not originating from my real browser?

$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';

```
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = ''; // 'Pragma: '; // browsers usually leave this blank. 
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'  );    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,  true   );  // new
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  //''
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$pagedata = curl_exec($ch);
```

As stated, the verbose only shows a timeout on the ip address, no errors, no responses from server at url what so ever.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a proxy at work?

Comment: most likely, your browser is configured to use a proxy to connect, but you didn't configure your curl code to do the same.